# SQL- Query to fetch the row having a maximum date below a certain date

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Sorry I couldn't explain this better in the title. Here is essentially what I need to accomplish:

```
Entity table: entity_id

BenchHistory table: entity_id, bench_id, bench_effective_date

Summary table: entity_id, effective_date
```

That is the database layout in a nutshell. This query finds each entity's `effective_date` from the `Summary` table. It also needs to find the `bench_id` for that particular date, by looking through the `BenchHistory` table and finding the maximum `bench_effective_date` that is less than `effective_date` where `BenchHistory.entity_id = Entity.entity_id`.

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT
    Entity.entity_id
    Summary.effective_date
    BenchHistory.bench_id
FROM
    Entity
JOIN Summary ON Entity.entity_id = Summary.entity_id
JOIN BenchHistory ON Entity.entity_id = BenchHistory.entity_id
```

Pretty simple, the bench part is what I'm having trouble with. How do I select only one `BenchHistory.bench_id`, that must be the most recent relative to `Summary.effective_date`?

For clarity, Each entity has many corresponding `effective_dates` and many corresponding `bench_ids`, but only one `bench_id` can be "valid" at a time (the most recent one). I am trying to find each row's "valid" `bench_id` depending on that row's `effective_date`. I need to do this by determining which `bench_id` has a `bench_effective_date` less than `effective_date`.

Here is an example of a query that I have, maybe it will be easier to visualize then.

```
SELECT
    Entity.entity_id
    BenchHistory.bench_id
    Summary.effective_date
    BenchHistory.bench_effective_date
FROM
    Entity
JOIN Summary ON Entity.entity_id = Summary.entity_id
JOIN BenchHistory ON Entity.entity_id = BenchHistory.entity_id
```

This will give output like:

```
entity_id    bench_id    effective_date    bench_effective_date
1            120         1/31/2011         6/30/2003
1            121         1/31/2011         3/22/2005
1            122         1/31/2011         11/03/2008
1            123         1/31/2011         1/21/2011
1            124         12/30/2010        5/15/2010
1            125         12/30/2010        10/06/2010
```

What I want to grab, is just `bench_id` 123 for 1/31, as it is the most recent bench for `entity_id = 1` and `bench_id` 125 for 12/30, etc. So a result set:

```
entity_id    bench_id    effective_date    bench_effective_date
1            123         1/31/2011         1/21/2011
1            125         12/30/2010        10/06/2010
```

Thank you, sorry if this is an easy question but I have been working on it for 6 hours trying all sorts of subqueries, aggregates, GROUP BY, and whatever. I am not that experienced with SQL.

:)

Comment: What is your Database version? and can you post some sample data?

Comment: SQL Server 2005, I just edited OP with some additional info.

Comment: Thanks Logan. Deleted my answer as it was specific to Oracle.

Comment: @Logan when you ask questions you need to manually accept answers by clicking the check-mark icon in the answer. This indicates that it answered your question. If you rarely mark answers "Accepted" it gives people reservations about working with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is NOT an easy problem, it took me a lot time too. Basically the same question as [Mysql - Need to get latest of table A when referenced from table B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414678/mysql-need-to-get-latest-of-table-a-when-referenced-from-table-b/6790717#6790717) and is related to mysql feature request http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=2020 , see it for info.

Maybe easiest for you is to follow this example:

Suppose you have table with price for each goods in each store. For each goods, you want to see the minimal price and the related store, in which you get it for the price! Exactly the same as in your example - you want a record with max revision.

```
create table prices ( goods varchar(10), price double, store varchar(10) );

insert into prices values ('car', 200, 'Amazon'), ('car', 150, 'CarStore'), ('Bread', 2, 'Baker1'), ('Bread', 1, 'Baker2');

select goods, min(price), 
    (select store 
     from prices as p 
     where p.goods = prices.goods
     order by price limit 1) as store
from prices
group by goods;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that and mark this as accepted for now. I didn't really know what to search for so sorry for the double post.

Comment: @Tomas Telensky your method will include `NULL` values when no such dated result exists rather than excluding the row.

Comment: @Matthew - good comment... But my example will not generate NULLs, it depends how you use it. If you make join in the from clause in the query I posted, then you might obtain NULL values for the store column, because the sql engine must put something there. But you could also do it different way, just don't add anything to the join, make my example query a subquery and join in the outer query, like in my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414678/mysql-need-to-get-latest-of-table-a-when-referenced-from-table-b/6790717#6790717 . Or, you can use condition `where store is not NULL`.

Comment: @Logan - no problem, you are welcome. As I said, this is a difficult problem for which I found solution only recently (and I'm quite experienced in sql).

Comment: @Tomas Telensky Including the `NULL` isn't inherently a problem and your comment certainly outlined ways to prevent the row's inclusion. I was just noting it for clarification on the statement's behavior. +1

Answer (score 1):

So you want to only `JOIN` the bench table where you have the max date less than the summary

```
SELECT
    Entity.entity_id
    ,BenchHistory.bench_id
    ,Summary.effective_date
    ,BenchHistory.bench_effective_date
FROM
    Entity
JOIN Summary 
    ON Summary.entity_id = Entity.entity_id
JOIN BenchHistory 
    ON BenchHistory.bench_id IN
        (
        SELECT TOP 1
            z.bench_id
        FROM
            BenchHistory z
        WHERE 
            z.entity_id = Summary.entity_id
            AND z.bench_effective_date <= Summary.effective_date
        ORDER BY
            z.bench_effective_date DESC
        )
```

On the other hand if you wanted to exclude benches entirely if they had any dates greater than the effective_date you might use a `HAVING` clause, please advise if this is the case....

Comment: There is no @pYourDate. I am trying to select bench_id where BenchHistory.bench_effective_date is less than Summary.effective_date, but the Summary.effective_date changes for each row.

Comment: This seems to work okay if I exclude the `BenchHistory.bench_id`. When I exclude, it only returns 1 row per `effective_date` and gives the correct `bench_effective_date` for each row (which is good). When I add in the `bench_id`, it returns many rows for each `bench_effective_date`, and it looks like every `bench_id` for each `entity_id` is included in the results as well... any idea why?

Comment: @Matthew answer: I'm afraid this way it doesn't work, because what Logan wants is to have an id of the record with maximum value of something (bench_effective_date). I doubt your code does this...

Comment: @Tomas You are correct. Logan edited his question, and I have edited by answer in response.

Comment: @Logan I have edited the answer  pursuant to your edited question